# render html code inside tooltip partial

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I'm using http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips on a app.

I have this rails code:

```
<%= link_to t('.shipping_details'), "#", :rel => "tooltip",  :title => "#{render 'orders/partials/shipping_cost_detail', :o => o}"  %>
```

The problem is that I can't render **html code** inside of `_shipping_cost_detail.html.erb`

For example If I add a `<div></div>` or `<br>` is visible like text on tooltip.

**How can I render html inside of tooltip?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are initialising the tooltip there is a `html` property, which specifies whether you are inserting text or html. By default this is `false` - you need to set it to `true`.

Something like this:

```
$('.shipping_details').tooltip({
     html: true,
     // other options...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use html_safe option, I think it will solve ur problem

```
<%= link_to t('.shipping_details'), "#", :rel => "tooltip",  :title => "#{render 'orders/partials/shipping_cost_detail', :o => o}".html_safe  %>
```

Comment: I have checked this option but is incorrect and is not working fine for me.